# How to solve multi type object data in single parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I declare this to receive options params value where value can be a single string or another object like `options?: string[] | IServiceDetail[] | IServiceAccordion[];`

But when I am trying to map the above objects getting an error:

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string | IServiceAccordion | IServiceDetail'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRnjT.png)

```
return options?.map(
                  (category: string | IServiceDetail | IServiceAccordion) => {
                    return (
                      <Text
                        key={category.title}
```

Comment: `Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'` I think it's pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the type is not a string before accessing the title, because a string is a primitive and does not have any property:

```js
   options?.map((category: string | IServiceDetail | IServiceAccordion) => { 
     if(typeof category !== "string") return <Text key={category.title} />
     else return return <Text key={category} />
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

because string is a premitive type. so doesn't have "title" attribute.
if you are sure that category is not string and is object and also has "title" attribute, you can use type casting

```
<Text
  key={(category as IServerDetail).title}
/>
```